# How can I update python on Git Bash?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, git-bash, python-3.7

I'm having trouble updating python on Git Bash
when I run python --version on git bash it still shows me 2.7 The thing is that when I run python --version in the anaconda prompt it shows me the updated version 3.7.3
How can I make it so that when I run python --version on Git Bash it will show me the latest version

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can't, or rather you *really* shouldn't. Linux subsystems expect `python` to resolve to Python2, and since Git Bash is (very shallowly) emulating a Linux machine under the hood of its bash shell, it would be a Very Bad Idea to change that expectation.

However, `python3` should launch your Python 3 interpreter.